# Динамическая подгрузка данных

Tags: javascript

Ниже скрипт для подгрузки данных в таблицу на странице из БД, но в консоли ошибка, и я не понимаю в чем дело.
Вот скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
setInterval(function(){ 
    $.ajax({
            url: "market_table.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {refresh:true}, // Передаем данные для записи
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(result) {
                if (result){ 
                    $('.my__table').html(function(){
                        var res = '';

                        for(var i = 0; i < result.History.Total.length; i++){

                                res += '<div class="my__table-row wallet__row">' +
                                '<div style="width: 100%" class="book__table-progress book__table-progress--green"></div>' + 
                                '<div class="book__table-item">' + (result.History.Total[i]/100000000).toFixed(8) + '</div>' + 
                                '<div class="wallet__1">' + (result.History.Amount[i]/100000000).toFixed(8) + '</div>' +
                                '<div class="book__table-item book__table-item--green">' + parseFloat(result.History.Price[i]).toFixed(8) + '</div>' + 
                                '</div>';
                            }

                        }
                        return res;
                    });тут

            },
            error: function(){
                $('.my__table').html(function(){
                    var res='';
                    return res;
                }); 
            }
    });
}, 1000);
</script>
```

Ошибка на строке }); после первого return res, пишет missing } after argument list

Comment: Уберите одну из `}` перед `return res;`.

Comment: @Igor на строке перед error: function(){ выскакивает unexpected token

Comment: а что в редакторе нет подсветки скобочек есть же возможность свернуть блоки сверните и посомтрие что лишнее

Comment: Вы убрали одну из `}` перед `return res;`?

Comment: @Igor да, вторая ошибка после удаления фигурной скобки

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строчка с фигурной скобкой - не там:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  console.log("timer");
  $.ajax({
    url: "market_table.php",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      refresh: true
    }, // Передаем данные для записи
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
      if (result) {
        $('.my__table').html(function() {
          var res = '';

          for (var i = 0; i < result.History.Total.length; i++) {
            res += '<div class="my__table-row wallet__row">' +
              '<div style="width: 100%" class="book__table-progress book__table-progress--green"></div>' +
              '<div class="book__table-item">' + (result.History.Total[i] / 100000000).toFixed(8) + '</div>' +
              '<div class="wallet__1">' + (result.History.Amount[i] / 100000000).toFixed(8) + '</div>' +
              '<div class="book__table-item book__table-item--green">' + parseFloat(result.History.Price[i]).toFixed(8) + '</div>' +
              '</div>';
            // } - была здесь
          }
          return res;
        });
      } // а надо - здесь
    },
    error: function() {
      $('.my__table').html(function() {
        var res = '';
        return res;
      });
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```